# How to store table cell values in a jquery array?

Tags: jquery

How do I store table cell values  in a jquery array?

Comment: This question is poorly worded. Can you explain what you mean, what you have, what you want?

Comment: Maybe also tell us how you want to retrieve the values. I'm guessing you'll want to store the values in a 2-dimensional array (rows and columns) so that you could use a function such as getTableDatafrom(row, column) to get the value of a specific <td> in a specific <tr>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iterate over each table cell and push its value in the array say for example you have table structure like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>improve your</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>accept rate plz!</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

you can do

```
var arr=[];

$("td").each(function(){

arr.push($(this).text());
});

$.each(arr,function(index,value){

alert(arr[index]);
});
```

**here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qNgST/1/**

Answer (score 2):

```
tableArr = new Array();
$('table td').each(function(){
    tableArr.push($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mytable').map(function() {
            var data_array = $(this);
});
```

Your table:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td>improve your</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>accept rate plz!</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// USE: var myTableArray = table2array( $('#idTable') );
function table2array( jTable ) {
    tableArr = new Array();
    var ix = 0;
    $(jTable).find('tr').each(function(){
        tableArr[ix] = new Array();
        $(this).find('th, td').each(function(){
            tableArr[ix].push($(this).text().trim());
        });     
        ix++;
    });     
    return tableArr;
};
```